# vuejs v-for, problema de referencia con objetos y componentes

Tags: vue.js

de antemano gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un objeto (array) al que llamo  'cartones' y lo quiero presentar en una tabla. cada valor de 'cartones' es un array de 5 posiciones, luego la tabla sería de 5 * x, donde x sería la cantidad de array contenidos en el array 'cartones'.. ahora decidí poner una 6 casilla (columna) a cada fila de la tabla, es decir, que la tabla quedar de 6 * x; Esa sexta casilla estaría representada con el siguiente componente llamado 'numerocarton':

```
Vue.component('numerocarton',{

props:['numero','ganador'],
template:`<td :style="{color:this.clasetd}">

<span :style="{color:this.clasetexto}">
   {{ this.numero }}
</span>

</td>`
});
```

A este componente le envío una propiedad (c[0].carton) que es igual para cada una de las 5 posiciones de cada array del array 'cartones'. De esta forma intento armar la tabla:

```
<table>
      <tr v-for="c in cartones">
           <td align="center" style="background-color: white"> 
{{c[0].carton}} </td> // linea de prueba para c[0].carton,  funciona
           <numerocarton  

           :numero="c[0].carton"   // no funciona, busca a 'c[0].carton' en la instancia y no aquí en el v-for
           :ganador="cartonganador"
           >

         </numerocarton>
           <td align="center" v-for="formula1 in c" style="background-color: 
white"> 
             <casilla 
              :formula="formula1.f"
              :letra="formula1.letra"
              :carton="formula1.carton"
              :miboton="boton"
              :botonId="boton.identificador"
              :botonEstado = "boton.estado"
              :botoninf = "boton.inf"
              :filasxcolumna = "filasTverdad"
              :factual="balota.f"

              >

              </casilla> 
           </td> 


      </tr>
    </table>
```

Toda esto funciona bien a excepción de la parte donde llamo al componente:

```
<numerocarton   :numero="c[0].carton" :ganador="cartonganador" >
</numerocarton>
```

más concretamente en :

```
:numero="c[0].carton"
```

Esta linea hace que aparesca el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual dice que 'c' no se encuentra declarada en la instancia (en el objeto data de la instancia), y este es el problema: no entiendo por que busca a 'c' en la instancia cuando lo devería buscar en el v-for y es 
sólo en esa linea por que es esta

```
<td align="center" style="background-color: white"> {{c[0].carton}} </td>
```

no hay problema.

Nuevamente gracias, de antemano, a todo aquel o aquella que pueda darme una mano para solucionar esto.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo? ¿Cuál de todas las propiedades del elemento quieres hacer que repita? Es decir, ¿cuál es la data que hay en la variable cartones?